# Getting current state of storyboard in c# windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am trying to get the current state of a storybaord.

I wanted something like if the storyboard have stopped play it again.

How should i go about getting the current state??

Below is my code to play teh storyboard :

```
void loadtime()
{
    ringingAlarm.Begin();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Storyboard` does not have any properties or methods that indicate its current state. However it does fire a [Completed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed%28VS.95%29.aspx) event when it has finished. You could create a simple wrapper around your Storyboard to track state, see [this forum post](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/15316/50598.aspx) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Storyboard.GetCurrentState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc672521%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to get the `ClockState`. This [ClockState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.clockstate%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) is an enumeration that has a `Stopped` property, which is returned if your animation is stopped.

Or, you can create a wrapper as ColinE suggested.